# Android emulator start slowly and lost from running devices

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have a problem with my AVD in android Studio.  After I click the run button and start a new emulator it is very slow when the android starts, the app doesn't install on it. When it is finally running and I click the run button again, I can't find the running emulator in the choose device window.

I've got a MacBook Pro, so it is running on OSX 10.10

Maybe I couldn't set up correctly the intel acceleration, but I don't think so it causes the problem. Running emulator is not found. Sometimes it works, but most of the time it doesn't/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use android studio (prefer eclipse) but maybe you can use a genymotion http://www.genymotion.com/ It's free for non commercial use. It's much more faster in eclipse than normal eclipse emulator. In my opinion it acts like real phone when eclipse symulator is always slow especially with hight resolution screen.

Comment: I think it will be the solution. I installed genymotion and it is very fast and works correctly on my Mac.
THNX

Answer (score 0):

I 've already installed HAXM but It isn't better. I try to do it again. I followed the steps. I typed the terminal steps,but I had some problem. 
After this command:

kextstat | grep intel

(got this message )

147    0 0xffffff7f82b0b000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (1.1.1) <7 5 4 3 1>

After that:

sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm

(but I've got that)

/Users/mecseidani/–b failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
/Users/mecseidani/com.intel.kext.intelhaxm failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).

Can be it a problem!?